# fresh install reporting no space (disappearing space!)

Tags: usb, disk-usage, syslog

I have done a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 and 15.10 x64 on a 256GB drive using the whole disk. This is a NVMe and I initially suspected it. After a few days of use the system reports less than 1GB and now 0 bytes in root on /dev/nvme. This just isn't possible! Unity never completes loading now and I can only shutdown from terminal (console).

I need to make some changes in the UEFI settings to boot from a live USB to get a better look tonight. I'm sticking with 15.10 as it supports my LAN and audio unlike 14.04 however this problem occurred under both.

Answer (score 0):

My main problem was that my /var/logs/kern.log and /var/logs/syslog had grown to 85 and 45 GB respectively. I deleted them. Then I rebooted and read the entries. I know better than to try to open an 85 gb file!

AHCI USB 3.0 related error appeared over and over. My mainboard has usb 3.1 that I disabled in the bios as a quick fix since I don't need them now. These two logs are not growing now. However something else is slowly (much slower) taking space as the computer sits idle. I will have to track it down.

The USB 3.1 controller is an ASMedia ASM1142 Controller.

Once booted back in to Ubuntu I used the following to commands to make analysis of where the space was going.

```
sudo apt-get install gksu
gksudo baobab
```

That is root gui mode of Disk Usage Analyzer